# Why is it safe to generate the secret key and masking vectors using rejection sampling in CRYSTALS-Dilithium?

Tags: signature, post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, side-channel-attack, dilithium

In [CRYSTALS-Dilithium](https://pq-crystals.org/dilithium/data/dilithium-specification.pdf) module lattice-based digital signatures, the secret key vectors $s_1, s_2$ with coefficients in $[-\eta, \eta]$ and the signature masking vector $y$ with coefficients in $(-\gamma_1, \gamma_1)$ are generated using rejection sampling on a stream of uniformly random bytes obtained from a cryptographically-secure pseudo-random number generator.

- Since rejection sampling is inherently non-constant-time, why is this
  not a problem from a timing side-channel leakage point of view?
- Protocols using discrete Gaussian distributions need to ensure
  constant-time sampling to prevent side-channel attacks. Why do
  similar attacks not work when using rejection sampling?

Comment: The term constant-time is a bit misleading (and I've heard people suggesting say isochronous instead). What is important is that the time and memory access pattern is *independent* of secret values manipulated. Them being constant is just one way of achieving independence.

Comment: @LeoDucas, your comment seems to be a perfectly valid response to OP's question, perhaps you should post it as an answer instead?

Comment: This is merely w warning about the notion at hand. A full fledge response would require me developing in more detail whether Dilithium does achieve this, and, this is not exactly my cup of tea.